# Does absolute convergence of a sequence imply convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

In my real analysis notes I've got that absolute convergence of a real SERIES implies convergence of the series. However what about absolute convergence of a sequence? Does this imply convergence of the sequence?

Comment: I have not seen the notion of absolute convergence of a *sequence* used anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. e.g. $(-1)^n$ does not converge but $\left|(-1)^n\right|=\left|-1\right|^n=1 \quad $ *does* converge (to $1$).

---

As NotNotLogical has pointed out, the exception to this is when a sequence connverges absolutely to $0$, in which case the sequence converges to $0.$

Comment: Worth adding that sequences which absolutely converge to *zero* will also converge to zero, but that is the only exception.

Comment: @NotNotLogical Well noted. Thanks!